# jQuery ajax call to update progress bar

Tags: php, ajax, asynchronous, progress-bar

I'm currently using a ajax call to start a big process on mysql !. during this process, I save a percent value in a database.

After this Ajax call to the PHP Script I start another ajax call to another php script that reads this value from database.

All calls are async true!.

The problem... second ajax call seems to start just after the first one finished.

```
function Get815(){
   $('#Pgbar').window('open');
   $('#p').progressbar('setValue', 0);
  getStatus();
  myVar= setInterval('getStatus()', 3000);
  startProcess();

}




function getStatus() {
    $.ajax(
            {
                type: 'GET',
                url: "lib/get_percent.php",
                async: true,
                success:
                    function (jdatos) {
                        data = eval('('+jdatos+')');
                        if(data[0]['result']===true){
                            if(data[0]['data']<parseInt('100')){
                                $('#p').progressbar('setValue', data[0]['data']);
                                return true;
                            }
                        }else{
                            alert('dio false');
                        };

                    }


            });
}


function startProcess() {
    $.ajax(
            {
                type: 'GET',
                url: "815/815.php",
                async: true,
                success: function(jdatos) {
                  data = eval('('+jdatos+')');
                  if(data[0]['result']===true){
                     alert('Finished');
                  }else{
                     alert('Error');

                  }
                }
            });
}
```

Here part of Big Process Script
    ..
    ..
    logger('counter ' .$nPercent . ' nCounter ' . $nCounter . ' nTotal ' . $nTotal);

```
$stmt = $db->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare("update `percent` set value=?");
if($stmt===false){ logger('SQL Prepare Error');}
$rc=$stmt->bind_param('s', $nPercent );
if($rc===false){ logger('SQL Bind Error');}
if($stmt->execute()==false){ logger('SQL Execute Error ' . $stmt->error); };
$stmt->close();  
..
..
..
$db->close();
$aReturn[]= array('result'=>true );
exit(json_encode($aReturn));
```

Logger function save to a log database... in that way I can see in real time whats is going on during the process.

now part of get_percent.php

```
..
..
$cSelectNodes="select value from percent";
if(!$result1 = $db->query($cSelectNodes))
{
    debug('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
    $aReturn[]= array('result'=>false );
    exit(json_encode($aReturn)); 
}
while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
    $nPercent="";
    $nPercent=$row['value'];
}
$result1->close();
$db->close();

$aReturn[]= array('result'=>true , 'data'=> $nPercent);
exit(json_encode($aReturn));
```

Just after 815.php has finished , then the progress bar get reflected but with the last percent taken from database.

does anyone knows why this is happening?

Kind Regards,

Comment: yes, and? that's what an asynchronous call is. start the call, then move onwards. If you want the second call to wait for the first, then you'll need a synchronous call.

Comment: I dont want second waiting the first one... but in fact thats is whats is happenning! ... second call should start at the same moment but start after the first one finished. Second call should read percent value from MySql but it start after the first one!

Comment: are you using sessions? default file-based sessions lock the session file while it's in use, forcing all requests using the same session to effectively become serialized. `session_write_close()` in any long-running code will fix that.

Comment: session_write_close() should be used after storing data on session? the same after reading?

Comment: sorry... I'm not using sessions !... (I also tried with same problem)... I'm storing information on MySQL ! take a look on the attached code.